# How to make a TextView occupy all free space in the middle?

Tags: android, layout

I'm writing an Android app, I have a EditText on top, several bottoms on bottom. I implemented this using Relative layout.

In the middle I have a TextView. But the problem is that it occupies all the space under the EditText including the space where the buttons are.

I want it to end right before the buttons. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Add your layout xml file to the question, please.

Comment: +1, Alex its really good question with snaps of layout that you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do that layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:width="fill_parent"
  android:height="fill_parent">

  <EditText android:id="@+id/top_Layout"
    android:width="fill_parent"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:width="fill_parent"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/center_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_Layout"
    android:layout_above="@id/buttons"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need. I had the layout_below option, but I didn't know you could use both

Answer (score 2):

Put your buttons in a linearLayout(orientation=horizontal). Use [layout_alignParentBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignParentBottom) to put this linearLayout at the bottom. Similarly, use [layout_alignParentTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignParentTop) for your editText.

Comment: That's what I have right now... What should I do with the ViewText?

Comment: set layout_width and layout_height to fill_parent, layout_above=@linearLAyout and layout_below=@editText.

Answer (score 0):

Use wrap_content to your TextView Or add your xml file..